# Python OpenCV Perspective Correction for Rectangle With Rounded Corners

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

The script below (modified from pyimagesearch.com) attempts to correct the perspective of a scanned card to rotate and crop the image. I have the final code that does the transformation, but the bounding rectangle drawn prior to that is not acting as expected. This is the original image:

[image: Original]

Code:

```
# import the necessary packages
from skimage.filters import threshold_local
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils

# load the image and compute the ratio of the old height
# to the new height, clone it, and resize it
image = cv2.imread('cards/red8.jpg')
ratio = image.shape[0] / 500.0
orig = image.copy()
image = imutils.resize(image, height = 500)

# convert the image to grayscale, blur it, and find edges
# in the image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(1,1),1000)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 75, 200)

# find the contours in the edged image, keeping only the
# largest ones, and initialize the screen contour
cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]

# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
    # approximate the contour
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)

    # if our approximated contour has four points, then we
    # can assume that we have found our screen
    if len(approx) == 4:
        screenCnt = approx
        break

cv2.drawContours(image, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

The output of the drawn box seems to be thrown off by the rounded corners and throws off the perspective correction, butting off slight portions of the straight edge of the card.

[image: Box]

Is there anything I can do to get a proper bounding rectangle accounting for the curved edges?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the background uniformly gray in all sample images?

Comment: Yes they are the same. There are nine cards per image. I was trying to make the code work for one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the original contour points instead of the approximation.

```
if len(approx) == 4:
    screenCnt = approx
    ((x,y),(w,h),angle) = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    rows,cols = image.shape[:2]
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((int(cols/2),int(rows/2)), angle, 1.0)
    nimg = cv2.warpAffine(image,M,(cols,rows))          
    break
```

[image: result]

Comment: I'm not able to re-produce that image result. @zindarod, was there anything else you changed? Also, is it possible to crop to just the card (removing the gray background except the corners) with this method?

Answer (score 0):

I use some priors in order to process detection and rectification (warping) of image.
I details in the comments the main steps and what they does.
The only thing is you need the OpenCV's contribution module to make it work properly.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def show(I):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    if I.ndim == 2:
        plt.imshow(I,cmap='gray')
    else:
        plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(I,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

def process_borders(I, lower_intensity=90,upper_intensity=100):
    I = cv2.bilateralFilter(I,-1,3,5)

    channels = cv2.split(I)

    borders = 255*np.ones(I.shape[:2],np.uint8)

    for channel in channels:
    #   Apply a prior on about the colours of interest on each channel.    
        mask = cv2.inRange(channel,lower_intensity,upper_intensity)


    #   Refine the contours
        mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,None,iterations=4)
    #   Only the pixel which have been on each mask are kept
        borders = cv2.bitwise_and(borders,mask)

    # Bitwise not in order to segment the card and not the borders
    borders = cv2.bitwise_not(borders)

    # Use a edge detector on the segmentation image in order to find the contours
    sx = cv2.Sobel(borders,cv2.CV_32F,1,0)
    sy = cv2.Sobel(borders,cv2.CV_32F,0,1)
    m = cv2.magnitude(sx,sy)
    # Refine the contours thickness
    m = cv2.normalize(m,None,0.,255.,cv2.NORM_MINMAX,cv2.CV_8U)
    m = cv2.ximgproc.thinning(m)

    _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(m, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    tmp = np.zeros(m.shape,np.uint8)
    borders = cv2.drawContours(tmp,contours,-1,255,hierarchy=hierarchy)

    return borders, contours[0]

def remove_rotation(I,borders, contours):
    # From the contours points find the angle
    ((_,_),(_,_),angle) = cv2.minAreaRect(contours)

    rows, cols = borders.shape

    # From the angle get and apply the transformation matrix to the original image and the border image
    mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols//2,rows//2), angle, 1.0)
    I = cv2.warpAffine(I,mat,(cols,rows))
    mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols//2,rows//2), angle, 1.0)
    borders = cv2.warpAffine(borders,mat,(cols,rows))

    # Update the contours.
    _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(borders, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    return I,borders,contours


I = cv2.imread('/home/smile/Downloads/card.jpg')

show(I)

borders, contours = process_borders(I)

I,borders,contours = remove_rotation(I,borders,contours)

I = cv2.drawContours(I,contours,-1,(0,255,0))

# Fine and rectified borders
show(I)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm seems just fine.

> Is there anything I can do to get a proper bounding rectangle accounting for the curved edges?

Yes. Firstly opencv's findCountours already has what you want - it's in the variable `c`. Use that  instead of `approx` (see code). Now for the bounding rectangle, use `cv2.boundingRect` which would return the top-left corner, width and height of the bounding rectangle to the given set of points.

```
# ...    
# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
    # approximate the contour
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)

    if len(approx) == 4:
        # Found the countour is "like" rectangle, use that countour
        screenCnt = c # <-- Take contour Here
        break

cv2.drawContours(image, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(screenCnt) # <-- Get rectangle here
cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow("image",image);
while(0xff & cv2.waitKey(1) != ord('q')):pass
cv2.destroyAllWindows();
```

[image: Curvy contour with Bounding rectangle]

Comment: It works if the object is near to a perfect rectangle. Thinking on captured images with a camera, it could have a perspective distortion. Then the rectangle doesn't fit